# File size conflict

Tags: files, aix, size

I am new to UNIX and have a doubt about file size in UNIX (AIX).
`ls -ltr` shows me `fileA` size as 59096.
As per my knowledge this is in bytes ,so it is nearly = 0.06 MB
However, a script which should `zip` files greater than 1MB, also zips this file:

```
find [dir] -type f -size +1M -exec gzip {} \;
```

Based on my testing it evaluates the same `fileA` size to be 115 MB and hence compresses the file.

Can some one please help. My aim is to zip all files above 1 MB.

Comment: What testing did you perform that gave you a file size of 115 MB? Also, what does 'ls -lh fileA' return?

Comment: The find command should work. For me it lists only the files that are 1MiB + 1 Byte (1048577 bytes) or larger.

Comment: Need further details: Exact environment (distribution, version), programs involved? Everything up to date?

Comment: Are you sure you did "+1M" ?  If you did "1M" instead it would find all the files sized 1B to 1M

Comment: ls -lh is not supported.
I get an error saying flag 'h' not found.
To test i had four files, with the above code all 4 were listed.
i changed my script from +1M to +100M and then +110M, all 4 were yet zipped. Around +115M the smallest file was not zipped and all other 3 were zipped.

Comment: system details:
uname -a gives
AIX [host name] 1 6 [Machine id]

Comment: ls -lrt gives file A size as 59606.
du -sm gives 0.06

So 59606 may be in bytes, since 59606/(1024*1024) comes to the same.
So maybe this file is actually 0.06MB.
Then why does my script with command find [dir] -type f -size +100MB -exec gzip {} \;
yet zip this file?
This is a huge difference 0.06MB and 115MB.

Comment: Can any one help?This is yet unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

AIX's `find` doesn't appear to support +1M.

From the man page,

> -size n
>
> Evaluates to the value True if the file is the specified n of blocks long (512 bytes per block). The file size is rounded up to the nearest block for comparison.
>
> -size nc
>
> Evaluates to the value True if the file is exactly the specified n of bytes long. Adding c to the end of the n variable
>   indicates that the size of the file is measured in individual bytes
>   not blocks.

You should be able to use,

`find [dir] -type f -size +1048575c -exec gzip {} \;`